# How calibrate Quanta touchscreen?

Tags: 10.04, input-devices

Greetings! I was able to make my Quanta touchscreen (built into a Gateway ZX4800) using [these instructions](http://www.bytetips.com/touchscreen-support-ubuntu/) but it badly needs to be calibrated. I'd like to use [this calibrator](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/xinput_calibrator) but I am a newbie, and the instructions there are very Linux. Could someone tell me the command prompt commands I need to install that xinput_calibrator program in Ubuntu 10.04?  thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

According to the page you link a person maintains a PPA of xinput-calibrator [here](https://launchpad.net/~tias/+archive/xinput-calibrator-ppa).

Follow [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them) to add `ppa:tias/xinput-calibrator-ppa` to your Software Sources and then xinput_calibrator will be available for you to install.

Comment: I tried that program, and got it installed, but it doesn't actually re-set the touchscreen. i run through it's wizard, but the touchscreen is still way off. it is perfect in the upper left corner, but then the cursor (arrow) gets exponentially further away from your finger as you slide away from the upper left

Comment: @user5901 Add this information to your original question and then hopefully someone with more experience in this area can continue to help.